# Hadoop datanode cannot communicate with KDC but the kinit works

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

**Hadoop datanode cannot communicate with KDC but the kinit works.**

> > > sudo kinit -k -t /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab hdfs/symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal@US-WEST-1.COMPUTE.INTERNAL

**And the UDP port also is OK.**

> > > nc symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal -v -z -u 88
> > >
> > > Connection to symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal 88 port [udp/kerberos] succeeded!

**But in hadoop kerberos debug output, it always said "Receive timed out".**

> > > KrbAsReq calling createMessage
> > >
> > > KrbAsReq in createMessage
> > >
> > > KrbKdcReq send: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=216
> > >
> > > KDCCommunication: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=216
> > >
> > > SocketTimeOutException with attempt: 1
> > >
> > > KDCCommunication: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =2, #bytes=216
> > >
> > > SocketTimeOutException with attempt: 2
> > >
> > > KDCCommunication: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =3, #bytes=216
> > >
> > > SocketTimeOutException with attempt: 3
> > >
> > > KrbKdcReq send: error trying symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out

**But on symbio5 itself, Which has the Namenode and KDC and a datanode, it is ok.**

> > > KrbAsReq calling createMessage
> > >
> > > KrbAsReq in createMessage
> > >
> > > KrbKdcReq send: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=217
> > >
> > > KDCCommunication: kdc=symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=217
> > >
> > > KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=776
> > >
> > > KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=776
> > >
> > > KdcAccessibility: remove symbio5.us-west-1.compute.internal

**Can anybody give me some helps? Thanks very much.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I fixed this problem, just make the Hadoop to use TCP port to communicate with Kerberos, not  UDP.

sudo vim /etc/krb5.conf

> > > ...
> > >
> > > [libdefaults]
> > >
> > > ...
> > >
> > > udp_preference_limit =1
> > >
> > > ...

Comment: Not possible with UDP ?